# Scala head of empty List

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, interpreter

I want get first element of my:

```
var stack = List[Map[String, ExpValue]]()
```

How is it possible that I always get an error that it is empty although I do this:

```
if (stack.isEmpty) { 
var new_map:Map[String, ExpValue] = Map(); 
new_map::stack;}
var x = stack.head
```

Basically if it is empty add an element.
Why is head always empty?

Comment: No, you didn't. You created a new value composed of `new_map` and the previous stack and you discarded it. **Lists** are immutable, you can not modify them, no matter if you fill all your code of unnecessary `vars`. I recommend you to study more about the language, you can fix all this just with this: `stack.headOption.getOrElse(default = Map.empty[String, ExpValue])`

Comment: Thank you so much! @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepending list with element does not mutate the list, it creates a new one which contains new element followed by elements of the original list. In this case you can assign result of `new_map :: stack` to your `stack` variable:

```
var stack = List[Map[String, ExpValue]]()
if (stack.isEmpty) {
  var new_map: Map[String, ExpValue] = Map();
  stack = new_map :: stack;
}
var x = stack.head
```

Answer (score 1):

Values come in many different shapes but mechanisms to deal with them are the same. For example, consider the behaviour of operations `+` and `::` in the following snippet

```
val x: Int = 41
1 + x
x 
// res0: Int = 41 

val l: List[Int] = List(41)
1 :: l
l
// res1: List[Int] = List(41)
```

`List(41)` is a value in the same sense `41` is a value, and `res1` remains `List(41)` instead of `List(1, 41)` for the same reasons `res0` remains `41` instead of `42`.

Applying this concept to your snippet (after simplifying it a bit)

```
val stack: List[Map[String, Int]] = List()
Map() :: stack
stack
// res2: List[Map[String,Int]] = List()
```

can you see why `res2` remains `List()` instead of `List(Map())`?